# Why 64 bits output hash function is insecure

Tags: hash

I know this is a insecure design to 64 bits output size hash function. Is there any report or literature illustrate this condition. I want to do some relevant reading about it.

Comment: Birthday collision. Many questions and answers are on the forum

Answer (score 4):

The answer is easy if you know about the current computing power around the world

Bitcoin miners in 2020/1/17 they [reached 126.1314 Exahashes per second,](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html) that makes

- $2^{67}$ SHA256 double hashes in a second, and
- $2^{92}$ SHA256 double hashes in a year.

With 64 bit output from the hash function, you will have

1. 64-bit **pre-image resistance**, broken less than a second.
2. 64-bit **second pre-image resistance**, broken when you click the enter.
3. 32-bit c**ollision resistance** due to the birthday attack that has a 50% chance of collision. You will find a collision while your finger on the enter key.

In today's standard, the recommended has size is at least 224 bit by SHA256-224 if you consider all available NIST hash families after the SHA-1 which has 160-bit output.

---

There are also single super computers like [Summit](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/summit/), that can reach ≈$2^{63}$ SHA-1 hashes around one hour, ≈$2^{72}$ hashes in one year.
1